# How to implement many-to-many relationship in Java?

Tags: java

I'm working on a project that calculates the fee for volunteers, who worked at a party, depending on their working hours.

The following is true:

> - an employee can work at many party's
> - a party has many employees
> - an employee can choose how many hours he wants to work at a particular party.

eg: person A decides to work 4 hours at party A and 5 hours at party B, person B decides to work 3 hours at party A and 6 hours at party B.
- It's important to know how many employees worked at a party, because the budget will be divided among the employees.

I want to calculate the fee for each volunteer on a given party
How do I know who worked how many hours at which party?
I think the code I have written now isn't the best option, because the objects get stored twice. If I remove the list of employees in the Party class, how do I know how many employees worked at the party?

```
public class Party {

private List<employee> employees;    
//other attributes

//methods
}

public class Employee {

private List<Hours> hours;    
// other attributes

//methods
}

public class Hours{

private Party party;    
private double hours;    
//other attributes

//methods
}
```

Comment: How about `List<Tuple<Employee, Party, Hour>>`? I mean, If you have a many-to-many relationship, you can just have a list of these relations.

Comment: Storing objects twice really isn't a concern in Java.  Since you can store only a reference and not the object itself, you still have only one copy of each object.  Normally this is desirable.

Comment: What do you mean by "storing an object twice"? If you instantiate every party and employee once, there are no duplicate objects. If you instantiate one Hours object per party/employee combination, there are no duplicate objects. The code you show seems ok, now show us the code where the hours are assigned.

Comment: Don't you need a list of parties inside the entity class named employees?

Answer (score 1):

define class that represent the relation

```
class Employment{
    private Party party;
    private Employee employee;
    private Hours hours;

    // ...
}
```

create list of employments

```
List<Employment> employments;
```

Comment: Which class knows the list of employments? I suppose the employment class should replaces the hours class cause it's basically the same, just added another attribute with the employee refferenced? I did'nt refer to the employee because the employment is an attribute of employee thus I found it unnecessary

Comment: @thomas you'd typically have some sort of manager/service class maintaining the list of employment sand associated functionality, often a singleton.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why you need the double reference between Party and Employee and the Hour class seems to represent the relation

```
public class Party {}

public class Employee {
    private List<Hours> hours;    
    public void addWork(Party party, int hours) {
        hours.add(new Hour(party, hours));
    }
}

public class Hours{
    private Party party;    
    private double hours;    
}
```

The above are your basic data classes but you also need some controller class(es) where you can create new employees and parties etc. Typical in such a class you would have a list of all employees so for instance to get all the hours worked at a specific party you could do given a list `employees` and a party `p`

```
List<Hours> hoursWorked = employess.stream().flatMap(e -> e.hours.stream()).filter(h->h.getParty().equals(p)).collect(Collectors.toList());
```